# Under what conditions should a program use POSIX sleep?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, posix, sleep

I've written a simple TCP/IP client application that continuously checks for new data from a server. The thread that implements this loop is scheduled at `sched_priority = 0` and `sched_policy = SCHED_OTHER`. Essentially I've made it the lowest priority.

The server only sends new data once a second which means the continuous checking is somewhat unnecessary. However, I'm questioning whether or not I should use a POSIX `sleep` or if the fact I've scheduled it at the lowest priority is good enough.

Under what conditions should a program contain a `sleep`? Should I be concerned CPU over-usage in my application?

Comment: When you create a socket using `socket()` call, you can specify if you want to use blocking read or non-blocking read. Refer to `man 2 socket` for details. Probably you want to use blocking read. So when you do `recv()` or `read()`, and there is no new data available, that call will sleep and wait for data for you.

Comment: Or `poll()`, `select()` etc. and be able to handle multiple connections in the same thread.

Comment: Regarding `sleep` in general... In the past I used `usleep` on Linux and `nanosleep` on OS X to work around a buggy US Robotics modem driver. `tcdrain` did not work as expected, so I needed to add some delays to help ensure a `write` completed.

Comment: As @SamProtsenko mentions, a blocking read is preferable.  Your program can be more responsive and more efficient when it is event driven rather than polling and sleeping.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of sleeping, your thread should block, either in a `read()` call on the socket or in a multiplexing call like `select()` or `poll()`.

Blocking is like sleeping, except that it will wake up immediately when new data arrives.

Answer (score 0):

When having too many fd, you may use epoll() for better performance.